# Do I need 6 months validity on my Australian passort if travelling to South Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea

Do I need to have at least 6 months validity on my Australian passort if I will be staying in Korea for 2 days?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Australian government's website](http://smartraveller.gov.au/zw-cgi/view/Advice/south_korea) on travel to Korea, the answer is yes - your passport must have six months validity from the date you plan to return to Australia, although there's no mention on the actual [Korean](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/GK/GK_EN_2_1_1.jsp) [sites](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt) as to how long your passport must be valid for to enter, just that it must be valid.

In general, the amount of time you plan on staying in a country doesn't affect requirements on how long your passport must be valid for.  If a country states six months, it will be that regardless on how long you plan on staying.  The alternative would be "valid until date of departure", which is obviously different.